# how to change range_max from default turtlebot3 distance sensor?

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am having issues trying to change the turtlebot3 (waffle) default distance sensor parameters. Specifically, I am trying to change the range_max parameter to a different value. I have tried to do that by looking into several config files but it seems like I have not found the correct one yet. Do you know which would be the correct config file to modify the below parameters?

When I type the following command, I get the parameters listed below (with no change on range_max parameter when I tried to modify config files):

```
$rostopic echo /scan

header: 
  seq: 2684
  stamp: 
secs: 537
nsecs: 486000000
frame_id: "base_scan"
angle_min: 0.0
angle_max: 6.28318977356
angle_increment: 0.0175019223243
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.0
range_min: 0.119999997318
range_max: 3.5
```

I am using turtlebot3 (waffle) in Gazebo/RViz with Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317354/how-to-change-range_max-from-default-turtlebot3-distance-sensor?/) by [jesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/40206/jesus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using turtlebot3 Waffle in Gazebo, then the scan topic is published by gazebo (there is no real laser, it is a simulation created by gazebo). Therefore you will need to be looking at the URDF files loaded by the simulator to find the parameter.

If I am not mistaken you should find it inside the file *turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle.gazebo.xacro*

You can see it in the github repo:
https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle.gazebo.xacro#L130

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/40206/jesus/) on 2019-03-03**:
Awesome, I was able to find the .xacro file to configure those parameters. Do you know if you can add sensor noise within that file? I see there is a row for  but I am not sure if you can actually simulate noise from there...

Thank you!

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2019-03-03**:
Yes, you can add simulated noise by playing around with the  parameters. The specification is here: http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=sensor#noise_type

**Comment by [jesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/40206/jesus/) on 2019-03-03**:
Awesome! Thanks so much for the help.